# jQuery UI Buttons Toggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, callback, toggle

I'm trying to toggle a UI Button from a callback of a POST operation. The jquery UI Button would either need to have "ui-icon ui-icon-minus" or "ui-icon ui-icon-checked" as a span.class

I tried to toggle - but toggle only removes and adds back a part of the class - it doesn't exchange the whole class. This is where I'm stuck at right now:

```
$('#toggle-page, a.toggle-page').click(function() {
pageID = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
$.post(
    "webadmin/pages.toggle.serialize.php", 
    {id : pageID },
    function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      if ($("#"+pageID+" a#toggle-page span").hasClass('ui-icon ui-icon-minus')) {
            $("#"+pageID+" a#toggle-page span").removeClass('ui-icon ui-icon-minus');
            $("#"+pageID+" a#toggle-page span").addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-check');
          }
      if ($("#"+pageID+" a#toggle-page span").hasClass('ui-icon ui-icon-check')) {
            $("#"+pageID+" a#toggle-page span").removeClass('ui-icon ui-icon-check');
            $("#"+pageID+" a#toggle-page span").addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-minus');
          }
    }
);
});
```

I know the code above is not the right way... but can someone point me in the right direction?
The Id etc. are a bit nested because theres multiple entries that can be edited - hence the pageID stuff.

Comment: Oh - the first if will work - not the second one! so depending on whats set at the moment, it will toggle one way. with the code set like above it will toggle from plus to minus but not back.

Comment: Really all you need is an `else if` on the 2nd one, but the answers below are a much better approach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
$('#toggle-page, a.toggle-page').click(function() {
pageID = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
$.post(
    "webadmin/pages.toggle.serialize.php", 
    {id : pageID },
    function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      var node = $("#"+pageID+" a#toggle-page span");
      node.toggleClass('ui-icon-minus');
      node.toggleClass('ui-icon-check');
    }
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be closer to what you want. Always cache the return from a jQuery selector if you plan to use it again:

```
$('#toggle-page, a.toggle-page').click(function() {
  var  $page = $(this).parent('div'),
      pageID = $page.attr('id');
  $.post(
      "webadmin/pages.toggle.serialize.php", 
      {id : pageID },
      function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var $span = $page.find('a#toggle-page span');
        if($span.hasClass('ui-icon-minus')) {
          $span.removeClass('ui-icon-minus').addClass('ui-icon-check')
        } else {
          $span.removeClass('ui-icon-check').addClass('ui-icon-minus')
        }
      }
  );
});
```

Comment: i'm new to this whole jquery stuff - but it seems that you are mixing in some php? or am I wrong ($ sign infront of the variable...)

Comment: @Mark, not at all. Whenever you return a jQuery result set, it is common practice to store it in a variable that starts with a `$` so you can tell it apart from flat variables (booleans, strings) and DOM elements. Then, throughout your app, you know `$varname`  can accept any jQuery method ( i.e. `$varname.addClass()` ), but `myDiv` cannot and must be used like this: `$(myDiv).addClass()`. Hope that makes sense. Additionally, this answer is more efficient because it looks up the `$page` once, and looks up the `$span` once instead of `$('#' + pageID +...` which tries to find it by ID.